# CSS being overridden in Wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a div with 3 columns, each column set to contain a thumbnail image link. I've styled this div  - `.reading-pane` - to have the right margins and borders in order to accommodate my design. There is also an inner div
 - `row_inner_wrapper` - that is created by the theme I'm using. There is no width set for this div - it should just accommodate the three thumbnail divs. However, the `.row_inner_wrapper` div is wider than the total of the image divs and making my `.reading-pane` div extend off the right of the page.

I can find no styling that should cause this using Firebug. However, in Chrome I can see that there is a right margin applied when I mouse over this div, even though there are no such styling rules applied. I can even set `margin:0px !important` on this div and the margin remains. Any suggestions on where my phantom CSS may be coming from?

You can see the page in question here http://jpsingh.samcampsall.co.uk/galleries/

HTML

```
<div class="reading-pane">
    <div class="row_inner_wrapper">
        <div class="row_inner">
            <div class="themify_builder_sub_row clearfix">
                <div class="col3-1">
                </div>
                <div class="col3-1">
                </div>
                <div class="col3-1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.reading-pane{
background-color:#ffffff;
background-image: url('leftcolumn.png');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
margin:30px;
padding:25px 25px 25px 103px;
}
.row_inner_wrapper{
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the width of the block of code below to `auto`. 100% stretches it beyond its parent.

```
 .themify_builder_row.fullwidth, 
.themify_builder .module_row.fullwidth, 
.full_width.sidebar-none .themify_builder .themify_builder_row {
 width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Grr! Spent ages scratching my head at this. Thank you! :)

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

in your `.reading-pane` div you have class

`.full_width.sidebar-none .themify_builder .themify_builder_row`.

This class have a rule `width: 100%;`. When I removed this rule the `.reading-pane` div was positioned properly.

Comment: Right, and by the way there is no margin on `row_inner_wrapper`, it's just that Chrome web inspector is being unclear. If you set `row_inner_wrapper` to `display: inline-block` this will no longer show up.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was not quite correct.
@pgk Thanks for your answer - correct answer to Sleek Geek, just because they were first. Thank you :)

Comment: @SamCampsall Actually pgk was first, look at the time both answers were posted :)

Comment: @vard thanks for your support, but if this is a SamCampsall decision :)